# Is it ok to reference a part of a std::vector subtracted from end()

Tags: c++, iterator

Here is my code which attempts to search for a string of chars "gold" in the last four elements of a vector.  It does successfully find the string but is this safe to do?  It works on MS VS2008.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main() {

   char random[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
   char tofind2[] = {'g','o','l','d'};
   std::vector<char> buf;
   buf.insert(buf.end(), random, random+sizeof(random));
   buf.insert(buf.end(), tofind2, tofind2+sizeof(tofind2));
   if(buf.size() >= sizeof(tofind2) && std::equal(buf.end()-sizeof(tofind2), buf.end(), tofind2)) {
      std::cout << "found value in last " << sizeof(tofind2) << " elements of array\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with that `sizeof(arg)`. This yields the number of bytes in `arg` rather than the number of elements in `arg`. Ignoring this distinction is okay only if the size of one element is 1 (e.g., a `char` array).

Comment: In this case, there is no reason for that `buf.size()` check. You are explicitly adding the contents `tofind2` to `buf`. So why test this size of `buf`? The only way that that `buf.size()` check can fail is if you have either a non-compliant implementation or if the `buf.insert(buf.end(), tofind2, ...)` invoked undefined behavior. You're already screwed if either is the case, and in those cases there is no guarantee the test will work. So why bother?

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes agreed, It was to show how I would use for real.

Comment: Appending what you are searching for to the end of the content to be search is a fairly standard search technique. There's no reason to check the size after performing the append when you use this approach. If the append worked the size will be sufficient. If the append didn't work -- that's a different story. There is a reason to check whether the append worked, and you aren't doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is safe so long as your `vector` has at least 4 elements in it: iterators in general can be moved through the bounds of their range, and random access iterators can be moved via addition/subtraction of an integer type.  `std::vector`'s iterators are random access iterators.

If it has less than 4 elements, this is not safe, and leads to undefined behavior (even before you dereference the iterator!)

If you want to be careful, you should check for that case.

```
template<typename Container>
auto nth_last_iterator( Container&& c, int n )
  -> declval( std::begin(c) )
{
  if (n > std::end(c) - std::begin(c))
    n = std::end(c) - std::begin(c);
  return std::end(c)-n;
}
```

which is C++11 and works on any random access container.  Then you get:

```
if(std::equal(nth_last_iterator(buf,sizeof(tofind2)), buf.end(), tofind2)) {
  std::cout << "found value in last " << sizeof(tofind2) << " elements of array\n";
}
```

As noted by @DavidHammen, `sizeof(tofind2)` only works if `sizeof(tofind2[0]) == 1`.  There are some relatively easy to write `template`s that find the size of an array and don't have that weakness, such as:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t lengthof( T(&)[N] ) {
  return N;
}
```

which is valid C++03, and in C++11 you can make it `constexpr`.  (and you can extend it to `std::array< T, N > const&` as well)

Comment: I should have added a check for size of vector yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you can safely do that since iterator arithmetic is allowed (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/).

Comment: It's safe so long as `buf.end()-sizeof(tofind2)` is within `buf` -- in other words if `buf` has at least `sizeof(tofind2)` elements. Also note that using `sizeof(tofind2)` as the number of elements in `tofind2` is only valid when `sizeof(tofind2[0])` is 1. That's true in this case because `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.